# Being able to detect int's in strings, Python

Tags: python, string, int

I'm trying to seperate a number from a string in python. Basically I want it so if color == 'gray' + a number, then it will return that number. For example if color equaled 'grey23', it would return 23. If color equaled 'grey', it would trigger the else statement.

pseudo code:

```
# = an int

def func (color):
    if color == 'gray' and a # :
        return int(#)
    else:
        print 'pass'
```

Comment: That sounds like a relatively broken idea. Care to explain why and how you'll do anything useful with the result without getting type errors or checking types everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if color.startswith("grey") and color[4:].isdigit():
    return int(color[4:])
else:
    return 'pass'
```

`color[4:]` could be replaced by something more generic han the hardcoded value 4, but as "grey" (or "gray" - you use both) is hardcoded there seemed no problem with this.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Surely it makes sense to use simple builtin functions to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

```
import re

def func (color):
    try:
        return int(re.search('(\d+)$',color).group(0)))
    except AttributeError:
        print 'pass'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) for that:

```
import re

matches = re.match('\w+(\d+)', color)
result = matches.groups()
if(len(result) > 0):
    return result[0]
else:
    return 'pass'
```

Not tested, so it could contain errors, but this is the basic gist.

Comment: Change `*` to a `+` after `\d`.

Comment: That's wrong. `\w+` will greedily match digits, so for "grey20", group #1 will be "0". `re.match` does only return one match, and you should check for it with `if match: ...` because it could be `None`. OP wants to return the color number, so it should be `return int(match.group(1))`.